# Where is the Cinnamon LookingGlass log?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I run Linux Mint 17.1. When I log in I get a Cinnamon notification saying:

> #### Problems during Cinnamon startup
>
> Cinnamon started successfully, but one or more applets, desklets or extension failed to load.
>
> Check your system log and the Cinnamon LookingGlass log for any issues. You can disable the offending extension(s) in Cinnamon Settings to prevent this message from occurring. Please contact the developer.

Sure enough, when I checked the Desklets settings, there was an extension marked with "error".

Out of curiosity, I tried to look for the log message mentioned in the notification to no avail. There were no relevant messages in `/var/log/syslog` and I could not find the LookingGlass log.

This is what I've tried:

```
dmesg | grep -i cinnamon
grep -i cinnamon /var/log/syslog
find /var/log -iname "*cinnamon*"
find /var/log -iname "*glass*"
find /var/log -iname "*looking*"
```

Comment: "Desklets settings" = Win key → type *"des"* → choose "Desklets" → tab *"Manage"* (the default)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's in

```
~/.xsession-errors
```

---

Prior to Cinnamon 3.8.8 it was

```
~/.cinnamon/glass.log
```

Answer (score 26):

In Cinnamon 3.8.x the `glass.log` file was combined into the `~/.xsession-errors` file.

You can view and filter only (looking)`glass.log` entries on the *Log* tab of the Melange-Cinnamon Debugger application. To open Melange, right click on the task bar in Cinnamon and then select *Troubleshoot* → *Looking Glass*.

Comment: The commit in subject can be found here: https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/commit/ed07898f5fc05786b2ea68dae72aed4499cfbcf4
Unfortunately it is not explained why that change was implemented.

Comment: It happened to me after updating Fedora 36 to Fedora 37 cinnamon. Culprit was the ```transparent-panels@germanfr``` extension to be found in ```~/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions```. As a start I deleted it and after logout / login again the message is gone. There is a discussion at the [github repo](https://github.com/germanfr/cinnamon-transparent-panels/issues/49).